# how to override helm chart name in the helm package command?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a helm package in which I have a **Chart.yaml** file. it is stored under the **my-package** directory it has fields such as

```
apiVersion: v2
name: abc
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: "1.16.0"
```

If I run

```
helm package --version 11.21 my-package
```

it is gonna create the package file named **abc-11.21.tgz**

then I run

```
curl -u$USERNAME:$PASSWORD -T abc-11.21.tgz "https://bar/artifactory/foo/abc-11.21.tgz"
```

later, to install the chart, I am gonna run

```
helm repo add "foo" https://bar/artifactory/foo --username "$USERNAME" --password "$PASSWORD" --force-update
helm repo update
helm upgrade --install "my-release" "foo/abc" --version "11.21"
```

---

**Here is my question:**

I want to somehow generate a package with a different name by overring the chart name without having to modify the file. Suppose I want to name it **xyz**

it should package it into **xyz-11.21.tgz** as opposed to **abc-11.21.tgz**

Then I should be able to run

```
curl -u$USERNAME:$PASSWORD -T xyz-11.21.tgz "https://bar/artifactory/foo/xyz-11.21.tgz"
```

so that I can later do

```
helm upgrade --install "my-release" "foo/xyz" --version "11.21"
```

Note that the **name** field in my **Chart.yaml** file is still "abc". My **Chart.yaml** file is as below

```
apiVersion: v2
name: abc
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: "1.16.0"
```

**it is not**

```
apiVersion: v2
name: xyz
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: "1.16.0"
```

How can I do this?

like the version that is hardcoded to 0.1.0 that I override to 11.21, I want to override the name field to **xyz**

Comment: with `helm package` it's impossible. you can write a small script which temporary replace the name in the file. is it during a pipeline?

Comment: yes it is. I decided to use envsubst